# UIlabel which can detect clickable text or urls

Tags: iphone

How to implement a UiLabel which can implement clickable text and urls, i need this to use in a twitter application

Comment: Another twitter application? *sigh*

Comment: show Twitter updates is one of the feature of the app.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `UIWebView` and use the delegate to deal with clicks.

```
NSString *html = @"<html><head><body><a href="http://www.apple.com>Click me</a></html>";  
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

You could also use a UIButton with no borders.

Comment: I have a table view in which the cell have text that contains multiple clickable data,so UIWebView wont help, i need a Uilabel.

Comment: Not sure I understand why that would not work, care to enlighten me?

Comment: I failed to see how UIWebView handle clickable texts. It doesn't have an event for it.

Answer (score 1):

You mean a clickable UILabel that behaves like a UIButton?

Make a new class that is descendant of UILabel and enalbe the `userInteractionEnabled` to get touch events.

Comment: I have a table view in which the cell have text that contains multiple clickable data.

Comment: Oh, in that case this is imposibile.
Create a custom table view cell, that contains the custom UILabel subclass instead of UILabel. You would probabaly want to add a ivar like owner or something, so that the UILabel subclass would know who to send the touch message to.

Comment: nothing's impossible.  see how he did it here http://www.three20.info/overview in the "style section"